# Opening base64 pdf in IE using PHP, pdf.js and ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, internet-explorer, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js to be able to display a pdf in IE, it works when I directly call the function with base64 pdf (you can check it here in the paragraph related to base64: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/);

But when I call it through ajax, it doesn't work. here's is my ajax call:

```
function DISPLAY_PDF_FROM_BASE64(byte_string)
{
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../ALL/byte_to_pdf.php", //this is the file which if called directly, will result in a successful response

  data: { byte_string: byte_string},

     success: function(data){

        var w = window.open();

        var newIframe = w.document.createElement('iframe');        

        newIframe.width = '80%';newIframe.height = '80%';

        w.document.body.appendChild(newIframe);

        newIframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/html');

        newIframe.contentWindow.contents = data;
        newIframe.src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';
        newIframe.window.PDFViewerApplication;
  }
  });
}
```

N.B: the above works perfectly on other browsers i.e. chrome, firefox, etc.

In IE, the pdf is not displayed. Any help is appreciated

Comment: any errors in the console chief? your link points to code that uses a canvas ... not an iframe ... just sayin'

Comment: no errors, it works just fine on all browsers I have other than IE. The link displays an example of the file I am calling "byte_to_pdf.php". I am trying to display the result of that file, returned from the ajax call.

Comment: weird that there's no errors at all - perhaps the content has zero dimensions, so it's there but not visible?

Comment: You can try for yourself and see. There are no problems with the code since it works for me on other browsers. But there seems to be an issue related to IE which I can't find. 
I have this error "The value of the property 'atob' is null or undefined, not a Function object" this error is in the byte_to_pdf file which is working normally if called directly